# How to install with devtools and an alternate gcc?

Tags: r, linux, gcc, devtools

I'm trying to install feather from github using

```
library(devtools);install_github('wesm/feather/R')
```

But I get the error referenced [in this issue](https://github.com/wesm/feather/issues/114), that I need to update my gcc. I'm using Centos 6.7 and the default make tools are old, but I installed [devtoolset-2](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/) which gave me gcc and g++ 4.8, which I symlinked into my /usr/bin directory.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

$ gcc-4.8 --version
gcc-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

$ g++-4.8 --version
g++-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

I added these options into my `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
$ cat ~/.R/Makevars 
CC=gcc-4.8
CXX=g++-4.8
CXX_STD=CXX11
CXX1XSTD=-Dstd=c++11
```

But when I try to install my package it fails because it tries to link in from the wrong includes:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:76: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
```

What do I need to do to configure `install_github` properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the CXX-equivalent for C++11 compilation:

```
 CXX1X=g++-4.8
```

That should do it.  If in doubt, compare with R's own `Makeconf`.

Oh, and you probably do not need `CXX1XSTD` as the value in `CXX_STD` imposes it.

Comment: Perfect! Actually, it didn't work until I took CXX1XSTD out.